# add custom validation message for min value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i am using angular-auto-validate to validate my form. i validated min value in the below textbox. please check

```
<input type="text"
ng-min="1"
ng-pattern-err-type="minVal" angular-currency="options"
ng-required="newtransport.isFixedAmount == true" ng-currency
fraction="2" currency-symbol=""
ng-model="newtransport.totalMarketValue"
placeholder="Total Amount" class="form-control"
ng-readonly="newtransport.isFixedAmount == false"
ng-keyup="setTransportTaxExemptAmt();isFixedTaxLiableAmount();" />
```

validation message comes correctly. but i need to add custom message for it.
i added  ng-pattern-err-type="minVal" attribute to my text box. but its not working.

my message is as below

```
.run(function (defaultErrorMessageResolver, validator) {
    validator.setValidElementStyling(false);
    defaultErrorMessageResolver.getErrorMessages().then(function (errorMessages) {
        errorMessages['minVal'] = "Value should be greater than 0";

    });

})
```

current message

[image]

how i add custom message for this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you must have a custom `ng-pattern-err-type`. If not, instead of specifying custom message for property `minVal`, you could use property `min` which is specifically created for minimum number validation. Basically, you need to change this:

```
errorMessages['minVal'] = "Value should be greater than 0";
```

into this:

```
errorMessages['min'] = "Value should be greater than {0}";
```

Also, make sure you write `{0}`. This way validator binds the error validation with minimum value you specified in the input directive.

Answer (score 0):

Change `ng-pattern-err-type="minVal"` to `ng-min-err-type="minVal"`